# Installed application keeps disappearing - Notion/Lotion

Tags: software-installation

I installed Lotion/Notion from here: https://github.com/puneetsl/lotion

by running
`./install`

it works fine. But whenever I re-started my PC, the application disappears from my Application Center.

Today I started my PC and installed XDM Download manager, once the installation finished, the Lotion magically came back to my Favourite bar.

Why is that?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using GNome.

If you are reporting that the application is disappearing from your 'Favourite' bar, it maybe due to the item not being added to gnome favourite bar.

**Step 1 :** 
Make sure you create a .desktop file with the appropriate exe/icon :

```
 
[ECLIPSE]
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/absolute/path/of/executable
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/absolute/path/of/png
```

**Step 2 :**  You can use this to get the current list :
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps

**Step 3 :**  Depending on your need, copy the desktop file to either
/usr/share/applications/(if you need this available for other users) or ~/.local/share/applications(if you need this available only for your user).

**Step 4 :**  Get the current favourite apps :

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

**Step 5 :**  Add the new app into the favourite app list. Here is an example :

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'Terminal.desktop', 'Eclipse.desktop', 'EMACS.desktop']"
```

Comment: this is not what I asked. It not only disappeared from the Favourite bar, but also disappeared from the Application Center.

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that a .desktop file needs to be created. Are you not seeing the app in the launcher even after adding the .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: I cannot see the app in the launcher. I opened the 2 folders you mentioned above, there is not a file called `lotion.desktop` or `notion.desktop` (notion is the application I installed, lotion is its Ubuntu wrapper)

Comment: @Franva, I had a look at the git repo. The `install.sh` invokes `create_shortcut.sh` by passing Lotion as the argument. `create_shortcut.sh` is supposed to create a `Lotion.desktop` within `~/.local/share/applications`. But if it is not available there, you will need to create one.
Here are the contents of the Lotion.desktop file.

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Notion
Name[en_US]=Lotion
Comment=Unofficial Notion.so application for Linux
Exec="${FULL_PATH}/Lotion"
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;TextEditor;Utility
Type=Application
Icon=${WORKING_DIR}/icon.png
StartupWMClass=Lotion
Make sure you change the Exec and Icon to the ***correct locations***.

I am sorry, I cannot get the formatting correct on this. But essentially, you can take the contents from [link]https://github.com/puneetsl/lotion/blob/master/create_shortcut.sh

Comment: thanks man, I do have `create_shortcut.sh` there. In fact, I found that I need to run it every time once I re-started my computer. This script does not solve the problem.